# C - как рандомно выбирать значения из массива?

Tags: c

Есть одномерный массив из 5 элементов. Как в чистом C можно рандомно выбирать из массива элемент или рандомно перемешать элементы массива?

Comment: https://learnc.info/c/random.html

Comment: С помощью случайного индекса

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @DimaKuzmin напишите ответ на собственный вопрос, когда будет код 